# Switch package manager in computer tab in kmenu?

Tags: kde, kubuntu

Note: I use a localized version, so I need to guess the english names of items I describe. I could guess wrong, but I hope I made my question clear enough.

Kubuntu 12.04 comes with muon as UI for package management. There are two variants, "muon software center", which is the super simple variant. It hides all technical information about packages, esp. its dependencies. Nice tool for beginners and people who don't want to care about such details. There is also "muon package manager", which *does* offer these technical details. For more advanced users who want to know what's going on on their machine.

In the kmenu (kickoff?) "computer" tab right next to "system settings" muon can be started. However, that options starts the simple variant. How can I switch it to run the more complex variant?

Of course I can run it with Applications->System->Muon Package Manager or make it a favorite, that is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `~/.kde/share/config/krunnerrc`, section `[PlasmaRunnerManager]`. You want to modify one of the `service` entries, or perhaps the `.desktop` file it is pointing to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't help. The section only contains one line: `LaunchCounts=2 services_kde4-kcalc.desktop`, and `find / -iname \*kde4-kcalc.desktop` came up empty. I took the hint and looked into `~/.k/s/c/kickoffrc`, but I can't see muon mentioned in there either. Also grepping for muon in `/usr/share/kde4/` found a few hits, but apparently nothing relevant.